# Decipher Rails 3 Code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I hired an oDesk dude to write some code for me, but then he disappeared.  I've been trying to decipher it, namely because it doesn't work, and I'm only a Rails hobbyist, so nested attributes are a bit out of my range right now.

I have an sla that has a period_state (red, yellow, green) for 12 periods every fiscal year.  The user needs to set his sla's period_state at the end of every period.  My create/update form throws errors.

If you can help me decipher what's going on, I'd appreciate a point in the right direction!  I especially don't know what the p "******" thing is in the update method...?  Thanks in advance if you can help - sorry for the long post.

```
class Sla < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :period_states, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :period_states, :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }


class PeriodState < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sla

class PeriodStatesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sla = Sla.find(params[:sla_id])
    @period_states = @sla.period_states
    #@periods = Period.where("fiscal_year = ?", @sla.fiscal_year)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @period_states }
    end
  end


  def new
    @sla = Sla.find(params[:id])
    @period_states = @sla.period_states
    @period_state = PeriodState.where("sla_id = ?", @sla.id)
    @periods = Period.where("fiscal_year = ?", @sla.fiscal_year)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @period_state }
    end
  end


  def create
    @sla = Sla.find(params[:sla_id])
    @period_states = @sla.period_states
    if @period_states.size > 0
      params[:sla][:period_states_attributes].each{|ps|
        @period_state = PeriodState.find(ps[1][:id])
        @period_state.period_state = ps[1][:period_state]
        @period_state.save
      }
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(sla_period_states_path(@sla), :notice => 'Period state was successfully created.') }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @sla.update_attributes(params[:sla])
          format.html { redirect_to(sla_period_states_path(@sla), :notice => 'Period state was successfully created.') }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @period_state, :status => :created, :location => @period_state }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @period_state.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    p "****************************"
    p params[:sla][:period_states_attributes].reject_if { |attrs| attrs["state_id"].blank? }
    p"**********************"
    @sla = Sla.find(params[:sla_id])
    params[:sla][:period_states_attributes]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sla.update_attributes(params[:sla])
        format.html { redirect_to(sla_reports_path(@sla), :notice => 'Period state was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @sla.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

period_state/new.html

```
<% if @period_state.size > 0 %>

  <%= render 'edit' %>
  <% else %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
  <% end %>
```

period_state/_edit.html

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Period</th>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
      <% @periods.each_with_index do |p, i| %>
        <%#= p.id %>
      <% @period_state = PeriodState.find_by_sla_id_and_period_id(@sla.id, p.id) %>
        <%#= p.inspect %>
        <%= fields_for "sla[period_states_attributes][#{i.to_i}]", @period_state do |ps| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= p.pe_number %> <%= ps.hidden_field :period_id, :value => p.id %> </td>
            <td><%= ps.collection_select(:state_id, State.all, :id, :state, :order => "state" , :include_blank => true ) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Enter/Edit Period States" %>
  </div>
```

period_state/_form.html

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Period</th>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
      <% @periods.each_with_index do |p, i| %>
        <%= fields_for "sla[period_states_attributes][#{i.to_i}]", PeriodState.new do |ps| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= p.pe_number %> <%= ps.hidden_field :period_id, :value => p.id %> </td>
            <td><%= collection_select(:period_state, :state_id, State.all, :id, :state, :order => "state" , :include_blank => true ) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Enter/Edit Period States" %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to check out the RailsCasts on nested attributes:

[RailsCasts on Nested Attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=nested+attributes)

`p` is a print method which is defined in the Kernel module.

See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html